# How is the tsc TypeScript compiler compiled?

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction

The wikipedia page for [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) mentions that the compiler itself is written in TypeScript.

How is this possible? TypeScript transcompiles to JavaScript, and JavaScript is typically interpreted by a web browser.

How is the `tsc` compiler binary generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While javascript is typically associated with browsers, it can also work on servers or the command line with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). Typescript's build process is composed of nodejs scripts.

The scripts for the typescript project can be found in their package.json file, [found here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/package.json). The `build:compiler` script runs [this gulpfile](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/Gulpfile.js), and part of what the gulp file does is run [this file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/scripts/build/projects.js). That file executes `./lib/tsc`, thus running the typescript compiler that's found in the lib directory, which then compiles the typescript code it was passed in. Note that the result is not a binary, it's a javascript file; the same (or similar) javascript file found at `./lib/tsc`

Answer (score 0):

> In computer science, bootstrapping is the technique for producing a self-compiling compiler — that is, compiler (or assembler) written in the source programming language that it intends to compile. An initial core version of the compiler (the bootstrap compiler) is generated in a different language (which could be assembly language); successive expanded versions of the compiler are developed using this minimal subset of the language. The problem of compiling a self-compiling compiler has been called the chicken-or-egg problem in compiler design, and bootstrapping is a solution to this problem.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)